Ubuntu alternative to swupd diagnose in ubuntu?
In Clear Linux, by using the command swupd diagnose it downloads manifest and checks the hash of system files. If there is a mismatch, it repairs the system files on demand.
Is it possible on Ubuntu to do the same thing, buy checking hashes of system files and repair them automatically?
